# Encrypt a SecretKey with RSA in Java

Tags: java, encryption, rsa, encryption-asymmetric, secret-key

I'm working on a client-server secure protocol where I need to use RSA in Java to encrypt a SecretKey for HMAC digests because the key has to be sent to the server. The encryption has two stages; first, I need to encrypt the symmetric key with a public asymmetric key, then, that encrypted message is encrypted with a private asymmetric key.

For this purpose I generate the SecretKey as:

```
public SecretKey generate(){
KeyGenerator generator = KeyGenerator.getInstance("HMACSHA256");
k = generator.generateKey();
return k;
}
```

Later, I use this code to encrypt any byte array with a public key:

```
public byte[] encryptPublic(PublicKey key, byte[] array){
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(array);
return encrypted;
}
```

The code for encryption with a private key is the same but using a private key.

For the RSA encryption I'm using 1024 bit long asymmetric keys so I have two main questions:

1. How can I turn my SecretKey to a byte array in order to encrypt it with RSA and a public key?
2. As the public key encryption produces a byte array with 128 bytes, how can I encrypt that message again with a private key if the key is 1024 bits long and can only encrypt a 117 byte long message?

Comment: A couple of comments. 1) Don't use defaults in cryptography, anywhere. In your `getInstance()` method always specify the full three-part transformation string. 2). Don't encrypt with the private key, instead perform *signing*. You use the `Signature` class for that. 3) Keys, including SecretKeys, have the `getEncoded()` method to return a byte array representing the key in some standard format. For symmetric keys, i.e. `SecretKey` instances, the byte array returned by `getEncoded()` is simply the raw key bytes.

Comment: For Q2: You could encrypt the ciphertext with a random AES key and then encrypt that new AES key with another round of RSA, but why would you want to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. How can I turn my SecretKey to a byte array in order to encrypt it with RSA and a public key?

That's called wrapping:

```
public static byte[] wrapKey(PublicKey pubKey, SecretKey symKey)
        throws InvalidKeyException, IllegalBlockSizeException {
    try {
        final Cipher cipher = Cipher
                .getInstance("RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA1AndMGF1Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.WRAP_MODE, pubKey);
        final byte[] wrapped = cipher.wrap(symKey);
        return wrapped;
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | NoSuchPaddingException e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException(
                "Java runtime does not support RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA1AndMGF1Padding",
                e);
    }
}
```

Note that this explicitly doesn't convert to `byte[]` first. That's because the key might well be within e.g. a hardware security module. In a HSM the wrapping *may* be possible, but the conversion to `byte[]` in local memory would usually not be possible.

---

2. As the public key encryption produces a byte array with 128 bytes, how can I encrypt that message again with a private key if the key is 1024 bits long and can only encrypt a 117 byte long message?

You shouldn't do this and you cannot do this either. The reason that you shouldn't do it because encryption with the private key does not provide *confidentiality*, as anybody would have access to the public key.

Padding is required to perform secure RSA encryption. The padding overhead (of 11 bytes for PKCS#1 v1.5 style padding) is there prohibiting you to encrypt with the private key.

Note that the entire operation: encryption with a private key isn't even specified in PKCS#1 - it's not a legit operation.

---

Usually the much more secure ephemeral-ephemeral (EC)DH is used to establish keys in transport protocols, using the private key(s) only for authentication. You may want to take a hint from the (draft versions of) TLS 1.3. Or you may just want to use TLS or the handshake portion of it.